# Svelte custom element updating not working

Tags: svelte, custom-element

I have created a custom element using svelte:

```
<svelte:options tag="my-component" />

<script>
  export let name;
</script>

<div>Hello {name}</div>
```

Which works when I initialise it in HTML:

```
<my-component name="Jane"></my-component>
```

The output on screen is "Hello Jane".

When I try to update name from the console it does not work:

```js
var mc = document.querySelector('my-component');
mc.setAttribute('name', 'John');
```

The output is still "Hello Jane".

Why does it not work?

Comment: Just tried to reproduce in a fresh Svelte Project version 3.44.0 and couldn't find any problem with the code, working inside .html and from console

Comment: With the code above? Or did you add something?

Comment: Used exactly your code from above. Instead of .setAttribute() the name can be changed by mc.name = 'otherName' as well

Comment: Hmm.. then this might be a problem with me running the custom element in a chrome extension. 
I will investigate and post a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The variable that you are passing are static not reactive. Svelte will parse the variable on page load and that's it.

Don't get confused by the fact that in the code you use them as a component prop.

I would suggest you to set these variables in [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage?retiredLocale=it#saving_text_between_refreshes) and use the onchange event in Svelte to run your custom logic